# LinearLayout border shape is not visible for the first time when android app is opened

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have LinearLayout with rectangle border stroke.  This linearLayout present inside HorizontalLayout.

But LinearLayout rectangle border stroke is not visible for first time after opening the app. But when I open the same activity second time onwards, LinearLayout appeared with rectangle.

XML code:

```html
  <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView_foodis_questions_1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_foodis_1"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:fillViewport="false"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/border_revcardquestions"
                        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_HorzView_foodis_questions">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:id="@+id/tasty"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:id="@+id/healthy"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"

                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:id="@+id/servedfresh"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"

                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:id="@+id/valueformoney"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"

                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**border_revcardquestions.xml:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:height="1dp"
        android:width="1dp"
        />
</shape>
```

**FirstTime When App is opened:**

[image]

**SecondTime When App is opened:**

[image]

How would I get the border visible all the time.

Answer (score 0):

May there is a problem with setting background of linear layout, you cant try setting background of

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView_foodis_questions_1"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_foodis_1"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:fillViewport="false"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border_revcardquestions"
                            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_HorzView_foodis_questions">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="80dp"
                                android:id="@+id/tasty"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="80dp"
                                android:id="@+id/healthy"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"

                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="80dp"
                                android:id="@+id/servedfresh"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"

                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="80dp"
                                android:id="@+id/valueformoney"
                                android:padding="5dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/whitebgcolorcircle"

                                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Or you can do is one more thing, set background of HorizontalScrollView as "NULL" and

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
           android:color="#000"
            android:height="1dp"
            android:width="1dp"
            />

</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks you. It works after setting color in stroke. With the method which I have followed, Why is the rectangle borders are not visible for the first time?.

Comment: If we cannot set the shape as background to Linear Layout, then how can we set the shape to any Layout without using background property in android?

Comment: Sorry i am understand what you want to say, but the thing is that , always set background of stroke.